# Can't push React component into an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an issue pushing a component into an array with React, code as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import NewPageSidebar from '../NewPageSidebar/NewPageSidebar';
import NewPageContent from '../NewPageContent/NewPageContent';
import TextBlock from '../TextBlock/TextBlock';

const NewPage = () => {
    const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState([]);

    const textButtonHandler = () => {
        const key = blocks.length;
        let array = blocks;
        array.push(<TextBlock key={key} />);
        setBlocks(array);
        // This works
        // setBlocks(<TextBlock key={key} />);
    };


    const imageButtonHandler = () => {
    };
    const spacingButtonHandler = () => {
    };

    return (
        <div className="d-flex">
            <NewPageSidebar
                textButtonHandler={textButtonHandler}
                imageButtonHandler={imageButtonHandler}
                spacingButtonHandler={spacingButtonHandler}
            />
            <NewPageContent blocks={blocks} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default NewPage;
```

For some reason setting an array directly `setBlocks(<TextBlock key={key} />);` works but the push doesn't. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Post your NewPageContent code, That's where the problem is. while doing setBlock directly you are not sending it as array you are passing it as single component. The NewPageContent component works only for single component and not for array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is not that the component is failing to get added to the array. The problem is the way it is being added.

According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). You should **not mutate the state directly.** Since state is a mutating operation, the state is getting mutated, and hence the re-render may not work.

Always create a new array and then merge the old part and the new part together.

```
const textButtonHandler = () => {
    const key = blocks.length;
    // This should work
    setBlocks([...blocks, <TextBlock key={key} />]);
    // Code below should also work, because concat does not mutate original state
    // const array = blocks;
    // array.concat(<TextBlock key={key} />);
    // setBlocks(array);
};
```

Comment: I forgot about this mutation rule on the state. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

React state management use [`shallow comparison`](https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-compare.html).
Based on comparison, it update state and re-render the component.
If reference is same, no rendering will happen.

```
let array = blocks; //It create reference to array block.
```

//Even we pushing element in array, we not mutating the state blocks

```
array.push(<TextBlock key={key} />);  // still array and block having same reference

setBlocks(array); // this will passed the same array reference
```

As reference is same, there is no mutation.So,no state update and so no re-rendering.

To make it work, do following changes.

instead `setBlocks(array);` use `setBlocks([...array]);`

OR

```
let array = [...blocks];
```